# How to Add 0.12.5 and 0.4.18 in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a survey report. In that report i have two numbers like 0.12.5 and 0.4.18. how to add these two numbers in excel. i need the result as 0.16.23

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible without helpers by using FILTERXML to separate the values in an array and add them, then using TEXTJOIN to format them separated by dots again:

`=TEXTJOIN(".",,FILTERXML("<x><y>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","</y><y>") & "</y></x>","//y")+FILTERXML("<x><y>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","</y><y>") & "</y></x>","//y"))`

[image]

PS FILTERXML only works on Windows computers.

Comment: In order to avoid the Textjoin that is not available in all Excel versions, i added a trick with formatted text and mmult... " =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( TEXT(MMULT({1000000\1000\1},FILTERXML("<x><y>" & SUBSTITUTE(A3,".","</y><y>") & "</y></x>","//y")+FILTERXML("<x><y>" & SUBSTITUTE(A4,".","</y><y>") & "</y></x>","//y")),"##0.##0.##0"),"00","0" ),".0",".") " does the job but it is not very elegant...

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved relatively easily using **Text to Columns** feature. Use it to chop your input numbers into 3 columns each. Then add them separately and finally join them together using simply string concatenation.

[image]